# lazy loaded routes in angular redirecting to home page

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular8

I am using Angular 8. I implemented lazy loading for a module named student.
the route is localhost:4200/student. this route lazy loads the student module. But whenever i am trying to go to the route, angular redirects it to home page(localhost:4200) and i am not able to see what is the error. i want to stop the redirection whenever there is any error to load the module.

**Note:Routing works find with only one component**
I removed all modules and components and checked for a simple hello worlds component and the lazy loading worked fine. But when i add modules and components to student module, the route doesn't work and it redirects to home page.

**Note:** I checked my console and the module is sent to the browser.

Comment: Add code snap here what you have done from that code we can help you to debug.